# Какие есть варианты сборки приложения Nuxt 3, если важны SEO и динамический контент (интернет-магазин)? Где размещать такое приложение?

Tags: seo, nuxt.js, vps, ssr

Разбираюсь в вариантах сборки приложений в Nuxt 3 по этой доке:
https://nuxt.com/docs/getting-started/deployment
Запутался, нужна помощь опытных коллег.

Я сейчас экспериментирую, собираю в разных вариациях простой каталог товаров.
Товары запрашиваю с JSON API на PHP + MySql.

Пока понимаю следующее:

1. В варианте сборки командой `npx nuxi generate` со свойством `ssr: false` приложение работает как обычное vue-приложение из коробки.
   Рендеринг происходит на стороне клиента. Меняю контент в БД и в приложении все изменения отображаются без проблем.
   Плюсы: нет проблем с обновлением контента, можно разместить на обычном хостинге.
   Минусы: проблемы с SEO.
2. В варианте сборки командой `npx nuxi generate` (свойство `ssr: true` подразумевается по умолчанию) генерируется статический сайт (SSG).
   Плюсы: сайт отлично сканируется всякими роботами и генераторами сайтмапов, можно разместить на обычном хостинге.
   Минусы: какие бы изменения не производились в БД, на сайте изменений нет, нужно делать новый билд, потому что prerender один раз прогоняет все запросы к api во время сборки и создаёт статический сайт.
3. Команда `nuxt build` собирает приложение в режиме SSR. Теперь можно разместить сайт только на VPS.
   Плюсы: всё хорошо с SEO (не было ещё опыта, так ли это?), контент обновляется.
   Минусы: не подходит для обчыного хостинга.

**Вариант 1** использую сейчас для сборки админок в связке с vuetify. Меня этот вариант полностью устраивает, так как в данном случае нет необходимости в SEO.
**Вариант 2** хорош для личных сайтов, в которых не плохо было бы иметь SEO, но при этом мне не составляет труда сделать новый билд при изменении данных в БД.

Собственно, в чём вопрос:
Как быть с сайтами для клиентов, например, с интернет-магазинами?
Здесь крайне важно иметь и SEO, и возможность быстро менять контент (добавлять товары в админке и т.д.).
Неужели в данном случае при работе с Nuxt 3 остаётся только **Вариант 3** с SSR и VPS-серверами?
Возможно, существует какая-то волшебная пилюля, которая позволяет размещать сайт на обычном хостинге, но при этом даёт возможность управлять контентом без пересборки?
Или может есть какие-то инструменты по автоматической пересборке при изменении контента, к примеру?

Не знаю, насколько удобно поддерживать много сайтов/доменов/клиентов на VPS.
Сам пользуюсь и привык к статическому хостингу с панелью ispmanager, автоподдоменами и прочими радостями.
Сомневаюсь, что на VPS есть что-то подобное (пока не встречал).

Коллеги, что вы используете в проектах?
Спасибо за любую информацию.